# How to integrate this? triple integral over a region

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I need to use a triple integral to get the volume in the region bounded by $y=3-x$, $y=0$, $z=x^2$, $z=1$.

I managed to plot the lines in the $xy$ plane: $y=0$ and $y=3-x$, then I got $z=0$ and $z=x^2$ in the xz plane.

From this I saw that I can use the following boundaries: $x^2 \le z \le 1$ and $0 \le y \le 3-x$. However, I'm failing to see what are x boundaries.

This is the Microsoft Mathematics plot I got (I had to rotate it a bit to get an idea of what was the region):

[image]

Now, how should I go to find x boundaries? Is it ok to take $z=x^2$ and $z=1$ then solve $1=x^2$ to get that $x$ goes from $-1$ to $1$?

In that case, this is what I did, and got a negative volume:

[image]

Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, $x$ should go from $-1$ to $1$. If you project everything to $xy$-plane, it is bounded by $y=0$, $y=3-x$, and $x=\pm 1$.

Comment: Thank you. And is it possible that after calculating the integral with those boundaries I get a negative number? I mean, can a volume be negative?

Comment: I'm adding my solution as an image in the original question, because that negative volume looks suspicious to me.

Comment: No it shouldn't be negative. Your integration limits for $z$ should go the other way, from $x^2$ to $1$.

Comment: But $x^2$ goes infinitely upwards over the $z$ axis... or I got that wrong?

Comment: That does not matter. It is closed above by $z=1$. So the lower bound is $x^2$, the upper bound is $1$, just like a bowl shape.

Comment: Duh! You're right! I wrote it ok first, then mis-write it when I set up the integrals. Thank you!!

Comment: Welcome! :) Glad it helped.